# How to use Google Sign In with new Credential Manager, and get access to user's admob statistics

Tags: android, oauth, admob, google-signin

I'm developing an app that's supposed to first get a user signed in, with scopes to access their Admob Data,
namely : `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admob.readonly` and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admob.report`. I wish to get the user's token and use to get the stats using Admob's APIs. I've got it working using standard Google Sign In, but since the new Credential Manager API is introduced, I wish to use it for authorization. Suggest me a reasonable method for doing this.

Any help will be appreciated.

I've tried using Google Sign In, Identity API, but I saw the message on the documentation that they were soon going to be deprecated.

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! A place for technical questions, not a place for mediumship and mind reading, we need facts, codes and errors. I suggest to follow the guidelinehttps://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi, I'm just asking if anyone can help me doing the same with Android's New Credential Manager API. I don't think I've missed any detail. I'm a newbie to the community, I'll take care from the next time.